Ways of finding upper bounds of hypergeometric functions
I realized that I don't really know any good ways of finding bounds of hypergeometric functions after ${}_2 F_1$. For example, numerical evaluation convinced me that the generalized hypergeometric function satisfies
$${}_3 F_2 (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2}, n+\frac{1}{2};1) < 1 + \frac{c}{n}$$
where $c$ is some constant. Is there a way to verify this and find a "reasonable" value for $c$? Maybe with some inequalities involving ${}_p F_q$? Maybe there's a way to use Steepest Decent on the integral representation? Some other tools I can learn?
Thanks!

Using https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/01/01/ and https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/ , one can get
$$_3 F_2 (\frac12,\frac12,\frac12;\frac32, n+\frac12;1)=\frac{2\Gamma\big(n+\frac12\big)}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma\big(\frac12\big)}\int_0^1\frac{(1-t^2)^{n+1}}tdt\int_0^t\frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}$$
$$=\frac{\int_0^1(1-x)^{n-1}\frac{\arcsin\sqrt x}xdx}{\int_0^1t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{n+1}dt}\to1+\frac1{12,n}+O\Big(\frac1{n^2}\Big),,,n\to\infty$$
